# SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I try to do Spring Security Login using JDBC when i run i got this
exception in my SecurityConfig

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
> instance of class
> **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is**
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private
> org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
> com.changepond.config.SecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]
> found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
> autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
> **Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService** com.changepond.config.SecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
> **Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate** for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)

SecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @ComponentScan({ "com.xxxxx" })
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
            
        private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
        
        @Autowired
        public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
            this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder()
        {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/loginPage")
             .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage")
                    .failureUrl("/loginPage?error")
                    .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")                
                .and()
                    .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/loginPage?logout"); 
                
        }
        
        
        @Autowired
        protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
              auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                  .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
            }
        
    }
```

> LoginService class

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class LoginService {
    
    private final LoginRepo loginRepo;
        
    @Autowired
    public LoginService(LoginRepo loginRepo) {
        this.loginRepo = loginRepo;
    }

    public Login findByUsername(String username) {
        return loginRepo.findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

> LoginDetailsServiceImpl class

```
@Transactional  
public class LoginDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    private final LoginRepo loginRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    public LoginDetailsServiceImpl(LoginRepo loginRepo) {
        this.loginRepo = loginRepo;
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Login login = loginRepo.findByUsername(username);
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(login.getUsername(), login.getPassword(), null);
}
}
```

Comment: `@Autowired
        public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
            this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        }` create default constructor and use `@Autowired private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;`

Comment: like this ?  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
 
 @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
  this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
 }

 public SecurityConfig() {
  this.userDetailsService = null;
  
 }

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  unable to create default constructor without initialization  this.userDetailsService = null; if i initialized like this got below error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)

Comment: `@Autowired private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;` and `public SecurityConfig(){}`

Comment: Please add the **full stacktrace** and also mention which Spring version you use.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  After Adding default constructor getting new error i updated the full exception above

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm using Spring version 4

Comment: Which version 4? Please specify the **exact** version..

Comment: Your `LoginDetailsServiceImpl` is missing an `@Service` so it will never be detected.

Comment: @M.Deinum thankyou so much Error is cleared, before already i have service annotation some reason i removed that then i forgot to add now added that after Adding error cleared

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thankyou so much for helping me to clear one of my exception